# Is there a fast linear SVM library with a good C++ interface?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, svm

I'm currently using LIBLINEAR. I am fully satisfied by it's performance, but it's written in pure C and the interface is not convenient. I have to write wrappers for everything and patch the code to use in consistently in a C++ environment. Is there any other libraries that are as fast as LIBLINEAR but are written in C++ and provide easier interface?

Answer (score 3):

The best you will find is [LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) in my opinion. Alternatives are [SVM^PERF](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_perf.html), and Pegasos (barely documented). They all have very similar interfaces. You won't find a library with similar performance with a C++ interface. Not because C++ is bad, but because these libraries are the state-of-the-art.

What exactly do you dislike about the interface? It's very intuitive and has hardly any overhead.

Comment: I don't like the interface because it requires too much work to integrate it in the project. Wrappers have to be written for everything to use LIBLINEAR in an object-oriented C++ code (for RAII memory management etc). The interface is pretty loose and many additional restrictions should be imposed on the input data (e.g. the features should be densely numbered starting from 1, the last dummy feature should have number -1). Load and save functions are useless if I want to serialize the model from/to a stream. And so on.

Comment: You could have a look at parts of the SHOGUN source for interface code. This may make integration less painful http://shogun-toolbox.org/

Comment: As I see SHOGUN uses a very strange manual memory management scheme instead of smart pointers. That's somewhat deterring, so I'd probably stick with LIBLINEAR :)

Comment: I would like to comment about Pegasos. The algorithm itself is easy enough to implement so it is not crazy to think in develop it. If @lizarisk is unsatisfied with other alternatives, this might be an option. By experience I can tell you that the implementation itself is in the order of hours and not days.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is quite comprehensive list of SVM libraries located here:

http://www.svms.org/software.html
and
http://www.kernel-machines.org/software

while it was previously stated `linearsvm` is the best solution, but it is quite "non c++" style. Yet there are dozens libraries, which are written in "pure" c++ and use `linearsvm` (or `svmlight`) under the hood, combining the best of both worlds.

In particular, **if writting your own wrapper is non an option** (or you need such a solution "here and now") I would also suggest **TinySVM** besides already mentioned `linearsvm` and `svmlight`:

http://chasen.org/~taku/software/TinySVM

as it is written in the c++ OO style, and has `svmlight` under the hood

Comment: While this is indeed a C++ solution, I guess wrappers like TinySVM don't solve the problem at hand. The OP may as well make a wrapper with the exact interface and options (s)he likes.

Comment: Of course one can implement such a wrapper, but I personally prefer not to "reinvent the wheel" and use already created methods, if they are done in a reasonable way. OP wants a method which is suited for the C++ programming. What is a difference, if "under the hood" it is actualy the same library he uses now (which is not true obviously, as `tinysvm` has a `svmlight` inside)? What would change if it would be written with asm code? The fact is, that it is a OO style solution, which is efficient

Comment: I disagree. Using a wrapper which you must then interface with your own software is by definition less efficient than writing the wrapper yourself exactly like you want/need it, which depends entirely on the rest of the software. To give a practical example: wrappers often reorganize data. I have seen several projects hit performance bottlenecks because data was simply copied/transformed *much* more than necessary. The tradeoff is development time vs. performance. Additionally, the lists of libraries you linked are quite old, many of those packages  are not maintained anymore.

Comment: I agree with your argumentation, if one has time and possibility to write own wrapper, it would be more valuable in terms of performance and everything goes down to the "development time vs performance" tradeoff.